# Using TSQL to find variance in minutes between two dates where seconds portion is greater than zero

Tags: t-sql

Need some help to verify this is the correct way of obtaining the result.
I need to find the variance in minutes between two dates where the seconds
portion of the date > 0.

List for the past minute, Variance = (Event_BeginTime - Event_CreateDate) where the seconds portion of HH:MM:SS > 0

```
    SELECT Event_BeginTime
        ,Event_CreateDate
        ,DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Event_BeginTime,Event_CreateDate) AS 'Variance'
    FROM Events WITH (NOLOCK)
    WHERE RIGHT(CAST(Event_BeginTime AS TIME(0)), 2) > 0 AND Event_CreateDate >= DATEADD(MINUTE, -1, GETDATE())
    ORDER BY Event_CreateDate DESC
```

Comment: To filter on the seconds, I would use `DATEPART(second, Event_BeginTime) > 0` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `VAR`:

```
VAR(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,Event_BeginTime,Event_CreateDate))
```

As for the date I would use `DATEPART`:

```
DATEPART ( SS, date )
```

Comment: `VAR` is an aggregate function that calculates the statistical variance. I think they just mean "difference" when they say "variance"